# elasticsearch get all docs of _version > 1

Tags: elasticsearch

After upsert data into es from several datasource using customised id field. I would like to confirm whether or not if there is a collision with es. After some study, I figure maybe we can use the condition _version > 1 to find it. But after all I am fail to query against _version field, Appreciate any idea about it. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to add another field into mapping, `updateTime`, which is empty in the initial insert; with every `upsert` you should set it to `now()`. Also the field should be searchable. Then you will be able to achieve your goal with query like `_search?q=_exists_:updateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to search on it. It's not indexed on purpose and it usually has an ephemeral kind of information in it, thus searching on it might not be ideal.

If you don't have too many documents, you could use scrolling and get back the documents with something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "version": true,
  "_source": false
}
```

If you have Elasticsearch 1.x, maybe this was possible with a script but with 2.x and 5.x this is not possible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/optimistic-concurrency-control.html) on your write operations to find out if there is a collision going on, but not after your writes have happened, which sounds pretty dangerous too me.

Also take a look at the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-update.html), if you know that you are always updating different parts. especially in combination with the `retry_on_conflict` parameter.